# Ext.require is required

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I start my app in extjs 4, using a

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
```

but when using my custom controls, I always need to explicit require this controls:

```
Ext.require('App.controls.CoCheckbox');

Ext.define('App.view.atendimento.FormAgenda', {
    extend: 'App.controls.CoForm',
...
```

My control:

```
Ext.define('App.controls.CoCheckbox',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Checkbox',
    alias: 'widget.cocheckbox',
    inputValue: true
});
```

Why I need to explicit declare those requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Extjs you organize your code in files then, your App.view.atendimento.FormAgenda is in one file and your App.controls.CoCheckbox is in another file. I assume App.view.atendimento.FormAgenda uses at least one instance of App.controls.CoCheckbox so, when extjs needs to create an App.view.atendimento.FormAgenda instance, it requires to download the file where App.controls.CoCheckbox is defined.

Basically, extjs has no other way to know the component dependencies. You have explicit them.